# Hard time installing Sitecore 10 external resources in Kubernetes AKS in Azure

Tags: azure, installation, deployment, kubernetes, aks

- I'm trying to install Sitecore 10 on AKS so I was following the steps in [Installation_Guide_for_Production_Deployments_with_Kubernetes_XP10.0.0.pdf](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/100/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_100.aspx)

  - Installed azureCli & helm on my local pc
  - `az login`
  - `az account set --subscription "MySubscription"`
  - `az aks create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name sc10aks --node-count 1 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys`
  - `az aks install-cli`
  - `az aks get-credentials --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name sc10aks`
  - `kubectl get nodes`  (Working fine)
  - I managed to create all this files based on the documentation

    - \k8s\ltsc2019\xp1\secrets\sitecore-license.txt
    - \k8s\ltsc2019\xp1\secrets\sitecore-identitycertificate.txt
    - \k8s\ltsc2019\xp1\secrets\tls\global-cm\tls.crt
    - k8s\ltsc2019\xp1\secrets\tls\global-cd\tls.crt
    - k8s\ltsc2019\xp1\secrets\tls\global-id\tls.crt
    - Paste TheCertPassword in sitecore-identitycertificatepassword.txt
  - Put a random generated string on *sitecore-telerikencryptionkey.txt, sitecore-identitysecret.txt, sitecorereportingapikey.txt*
  - Filled up those with random generated strings as well, this will be the passwords

    - sitecore-adminpassword.txt, sitecore-databasepassword, sitecore-collection-shardmapmanager-database-password, sitecore-core-database-password.txt, sitecore-exm-master-database-password, sitecore-forms-database-password, sitecore-marketing-automation-database-password, sitecore-master-database-password, sitecore-messaging-database-password, sitecore-processing-engine-tasks-database-password, sitecore-processing-tasks-database-password, sitecore-reference-data-database-password, sitecore-reporting-database-password, sitecore-web-database-password
    - `helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/`
    - `helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.replicaCount=1 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set-string controller.config.proxy-body-size=10m --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local`
    - `kubectl apply -k ./secrets/`

      - This commands succeeds and print: secret/global-cd-tls created secret/global-cm-tls created secret/global-id-tls created secret/sitecore-admin created secret/sitecore-database created secret/sitecore-identitycertificate created secret/sitecore-identity created secret/sitecore-license created secret/sitecore-reporting created secret/sitecore-solr-xdb created secret/sitecore-solr created secret/sitecore-telerik created
    - `kubectl apply -f ./external/`

      - This commands succeeds and print: service/mssql created  deployment.apps/mssql created service/redis created deployment.apps/redis created service/solr created deployment.apps/solr created
      - My problem is here, it succeeds but I never see it green in azure, there is always this warning sign.
      - Running `kubectl get pods -o wide` mssql, redis, solr status is always pending
        [image: azure AKS]
      - Because of the previous `kubectl apply -f ./init/`
- Running `kubectl describe pod` is giving me this result: `Normal`   Successfully assigned default/mssql-init-zd49r to aks-nodepool1-34023802-vmss000000
  `Normal`   Pulling image "scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:10.0.0-ltsc2019"
  `Warning`  Failed to pull image "scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:10.0.0-ltsc2019": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://scr.sitecore.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  `Warning`  Error: ErrImagePull
  `Normal`   Back-off pulling image "scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:10.0.0-ltsc2019"
  `Warning`  Error: ImagePullBackOff
- In the logs I can see those errors:

  - Error creating: pods "tunnelfront-67d969bc5f-" is forbidden: error looking up service account kube-system/tunnelfront: serviceaccount "tunnelfront" not found
  - Error creating: pods "coredns-autoscaler-868b684fd4-" is forbidden: error looking up service account kube-system/coredns-autoscaler: serviceaccount "coredns-autoscaler" not found
- I also tried to have ACR attached to the k8s service but this didn't help either `$MYACR="myContainerRegistry"` `az acr create -n $MYACR -g my_rg_AKS --sku basic` `az aks create -n sc10aks -g my_rg_AKS --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr $MYACR`
- I was wondering when if it's going to be used `sitecore-database-elastic-pool-name.txt` , so I tried one time when it was empty and I tried to install while it contains `ElasticPool` in the file, but it didn't help, the mssql, redis, solr status is always pending

Sorry for the long question, but you can reproduce the issue just from this steps.

Comment: Can you please re run the external services again and see the status of prod.

I mean this command

    kubectl apply -f ./external/

and please check the status of Prod in azure portal

My 2 cent would be it's related to prod throttling under the current load and it ended up with tunnelfront and autoscaler not found, can you please recheck the cluster size and also check if the DNS horizontal autoscaling is already enabled or not

    kubectl get deployment --namespace=kube-system

Comment: I also received the "Failed to pull image" message on the mssql init job. Do you found any solution for that issue?

Comment: I have this same issue and even tried to just do mssql by itself using this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-sql-server-containers-kubernetes?view=sql-server-ver16 - but I get your same issue. Did you find a solve for this? I will send a gift card to anyone that can help me. I have wasted 2 days now.

Answer (score 2):

ahmed

Check my scripts at https://github.com/bplasmeijer/Sitecore-Symposium-2020-Containers-AKS and check `2.CreateAKS.ps1`, do you have a `windows` node on your cluster?

`az aks create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name sc10aks --node-count 1 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys` does not create a windows node.

Bart

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to deploy a `Sitecore 10 Dev/Non-Prod Instance` you might give my `all in one` PowerShell deployment script a try. It's targeted for XM, I will be creating one for XP as well as time allows, or you could use what I have here as a template and just do it yourself.

Here is the repo:

https://github.com/evinruding/Sitecore-10-k8s-deploy-scripts

Your subscription account will need to have `User Access Administrator` rights in order for it to work.

I hope this helps

Colin