# Error on mssql-init container during the deployment of Sitecore to AKS

Tags: container, kubernetes, aks

I am following the production installation guide to install Sitecore on AKS. I am at the step of `Deploy the data initialization jobs`. I have run the command and it created 2 jobs in kubernetes cluster, one for `mssql-init`, and another for `solr-init`. The `solr-init` job ran successfully and was completed. However, the `mssql-init` job is not completed as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have tried to check on the pod by using the **describe command**, but it does not show any errors as shown below.

[image]

I checked events to see if there are any errors there. However, I do not see any errors there as shown below

[image]

I have tried to see the logs of the pods, but it didn't show me any logs of the pod with the following message:

> Error from server (BadRequest): previous terminated container
> "mssql-init" in pod "mssql-init-2jvw8" not found

Could someone please help me what the error is with `mssql-init` container and what needs to be done to go past this error? Thanks in advance.

**Update  on error:**
I have used `Stern` to see the logs and found that there is a SQL connection error. Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Prasanth Nittala Can you please try to answer my question https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27011/hard-time-installing-sitecore-10-external-resources-in-kubernetes-aks-in-azure    it seems you passed the point that I'm stuck on

Comment: I tried to remove all the linefeed characters from my secret files but It didn't work, I still see the warning signs (please check my question) Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed, Updated my answer, after you remove linefeed characters, you have to rerun the following steps mentioned to reflect the updated secrets. Have looked at your issue, seems like it is failing to pull sitecore  images. In my case, it was able to pull images fine.

Answer (score 4):

There were linefeed characters in the secret files. Removing the linefeed characters resolved the issue and the sql server was reachable.
Once you remove the line feed characters from the files, you need to rerun the

1. kubectl apply -k ./secrets/
2. kubectl delete -f ./external/mssql.yaml
3. kubectl apply -f ./external/mssql.yaml
4. kubectl delete -f ./init/mssql-init.yaml
5. kubectl apply -f ./init/mssql-init.yaml
6. delete and apply the cd.yaml, cm.yaml,id.yaml and ingress.yaml again in case you see errors connecting to DB on the cd, cm.

This makes sure the new passwords are updated and are used in the containers.

Comment: You are my hero of the day! Thanks! :)