# Unable to install Mssql init job in azure AKS

Tags: azure, aks

I was trying to install sitecore on my azure AKS engine. When I run the `mssql-init file` the jobs fail to create with the following error:

```
    Start publishing dacpacs Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: 
    Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. . Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired. 
    Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. 
    Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.. 
    sqlcmd exited with code 1 At C:\DeployDatabases.ps1:91 char:9

    throw "sqlcmd exited with code $LASTEXITCODE"

    CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (sqlcmd exited with code 1:Str ing) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : sqlcmd exited with code 1
```

Any help please.

Comment: Is the SQL server running in a container in the cluster or is external (like for example Azure SQL Server)?

Comment: Its running on the AKS container from sitecore development image

Comment: It seems that you are experiencing the same error described here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/error-on-mssql-init-container-during-the-deployment-of-sitecore-to-aks